# Django restricting certain keywords?

Tags: python, django

I got into this issue that i'm unable to resolve somehow.

So i'm running on Django 1.7.7 with two apps, models as follows

- order.Order
- order.OrderItinerary (m2m through table)
- itinerary.Itinerary
- itinerary.Photo

The problem here is that when i use foreign key inside OrderItinerary that points to Itinerary model, it works.
But when foreign key from Photo points to Itinerary model it raises me this error

```
<class 'itinerary.admin.ItineraryPhotoAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[1]' refers to 'itinerary', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'ItineraryPhotoAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'itinerary.Photo'.
```

i just don't get how two distinct models pointing to the same model could give me different results

```
class Order(GenericModel):
def __str__(self):
    return "%s" %(self.title)

title       = models.CharField(max_length=64)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
order_number= models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True, blank=True, default='')
itineraries = models.ManyToManyField('itinerary.Itinerary', through='order.OrderItinerary')
```

Second Model

```
class OrderItinerary(GenericModel):
title       = models.CharField(max_length=64)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
rating      = models.FloatField(blank=True)
order       = models.ForeignKey('order.Order')
itinerary   = models.ForeignKey('itinerary.Itinerary')
```

Third Model

```
class Itinerary(GenericModel):
uuid        = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=generate_uuid)
title       = models.CharField(max_length=64)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
price       = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
total_rating= models.FloatField(default=0)
rating_num  = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="number of customers rated")
```

Fourth Model

```
class Photo(GenericModel):
caption     = models.CharField(max_length=254, default='', blank=True)
photo       = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_photo_name)
itinenary   = models.ForeignKey('itinerary.Itinerary', related_name="itinerary_photo")
```

Comment: Can you provide your models and admin files?

Comment: Note that GenericModel is an abstractmodel contains date_created and date_modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in you `Photo` model, correct `itinenary` to `itinerary`.